Videocast built from Xcode 15 for iOS17 is not working
I am building Videocast framework using Xcode 15 to be used in a project , it is necessary to build this project via Xcode15 for iOS17 support.
Currently its building successfully and I have tried with both default and legacy build settings.
After build for any device iOS arm64 when I import into my project the import is Successful as well.
Since Videocast has delegates method for ReplayKit. After I use ReplayKit start broadcast its not starting neither I am able to broadcast anything.
Including that unable to get anylogs from UploadExtension for ReplayKit Screen Capture.
I need Videocast to work fine after building from Xcode15.3 and the screen share upload extension to work as intended
